In React, I'm getting the ".map is not a function" error when I attempt to map a list of objects
I'm brand new to React, and still pretty shaky on Typescript and Javascript and I'm attempting to make a React component that will iterate through an array of Account objects that would be passed into the component.
This is the code as it currently exists:
export default function AccountSummaryList(accountList: Account[]) {
  const listOfAccountSummaries = accountList.map((account, index) => {
    return (
      <li key={index}>
        <AccountSummary {...account} />
      </li>
    );
  });

  return <ul>{listOfAccountSummaries}</ul>;
}

I've been looking around, and none of the solutions that I've found appear to apply. One source said that the issue is that the compiler doesn't see the accountList as actually being an array due to the time difference between the program starting and the object instantiation, but I can't verify if that's what is happening for me. The thing is, I can brute force the code to work by declaring the listOfAccountSummaries variable like this:
const listOfAccountSummaries = (
  <>
    <li>
      <AccountSummary {...accountList[0]} />
    </li>
    <li>
      <AccountSummary {...accountList[1]} />
    </li>
  </>
);

So the issue is something to do with how the compiler reads the accountList variable. If the issue is indeed a matter of the compiler not recognizing that the accountList variable is an array of Account objects, I have yet to find a solution that resolves that. One solution I found suggests validating that the array is actually an array with this approach:
const listOfAccountSummaries =
  accountList &&
  accountList.map &&
  accountList.map((account, index) => {
    return (
      <li key={index}>
        <AccountSummary {...account} />
      </li>
    );
  });

and while that does get the app to compile without any errors, it also doesn't display the list of account summaries.
I'm really struggling to understand how Typescript works, so any explanation y'all can give me as to why this problem is arising would be incredibly appreciated.

I'm trying to understand what the actual problem is here: your title is for summarizing the problem, your post is for explaining what you set out to do, what code you wrote, why you wrote that code (e.g. what did you expect it to do), what you see it do instead and what debugging you already did. I don't see your post talk about that italic text. Typing doesn't exist at runtime, and so cannot guarantee that your function input "is something": did you check that you're even getting an array passed intoAccountSummaryList rather than just....nothing?

Try console.log(typeof accountList) what is the output? Also you mentioned react  having a compiler. React (currently) does not have a compiler. I would suggest reading up on virtual DOM.

export default function AccountSummaryList(accountList: Account[]) {

Assuming this is a component, this is not the correct way to do props. The component always receives a single parameter which is an object, and that object can contain an accountList prop if you want. For example:
export default function AccountSummaryList(props: { accountList: Account[] }) {
  const accountList = props.accountList;

Or using destructuring to do it in one line:
export default function AccountSummaryList({ accountList }: { accountList: Account[] }) {

Or defining the props as a named type, for clarity:
interface AccountSummaryListProps {
  accountList: Account[]
}
export default function AccountSummaryList({ accountList }: AccountSummaryListProps) {


Thank you so much for your help! We actually just covered useContext today, and I was able to get it to work well, so it looks like I'm good to go there! Thanks again for your help!
